# Manipulate an application using VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, launching-application

I have a problem in my VB code so I am now stuck. I am trying to open a certain application by my VB application code, this is done successfully by `Process.Start()`.

However I don't only need to start application, I also need to manipulate its User Interface, like button presses or loading configuration.

So how can I do that, given all what I know from the tool that I launch, is its destination in my machine?

I tried to google it, but I couldn't find good answer!

Comment: unless the other application is designed specifically to receive input from another program and take action based upon that input, (in other words, has an API (Application Programming Interface)), then you are talking about automation, which is way too complex to cover in one answer here.  If the program *does* have an API, then the API documentation would tell you how to direct the program.

Comment: Thanks so much Brian , so the main application should have API or Dll to be communicated with ,  also the other application should have way to deal with this Dll "API" ,  is this right Brian ?

Comment: if you want to automate button press etc. look at  [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)